# Close div after loop

Tags: php, html, css

I am building a page that displays posts from different categories.

I have no issue with the loop and the posts are displaying correctly but the second category header "Trending Stories" is getting stuck in the section "main-categories". I can't seem to close the section. I know that sounds bonkers but I can't see how or what I am doing wrong.

URL: [test site](http://104.244.127.200/~qmintest/test/)

```css
.main-categories {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 padding: 60px 70px 36px;
        margin-bottom:500px;
        margin-left:5em;
        margin-right:5em;
}

.main-categories ul li {
       list-style:none;
}

.trending-categories {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1280px;
 padding: 260px 70px 36px;
        margin-bottom:500px;
        margin-left:5em;
        margin-right:5em;
}

.trending-categories ul li {
       list-style:none;
}

.cat-row {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.cat-title {
max-width: 220px;
}

.cat-title h4 {
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 900;
text-align:center;
color:#000;
}

.posts li:nth-child(3) {
color:#000;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:900;
}

.posts li:nth-child(7) {
color:#000;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:900;
}

.posts li:nth-child(4) {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.posts li:nth-child(8) {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

ul.posts {
max-width:220px;
}

span.author {
color:#d6b4b1 !important;
}

.cat-label h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.cat-label h2:before,
.cat-label h2:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
.cat-label h2:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
.cat-label h2:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

section.cat-label {
max-width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 75px;
}

section.cat-label h2 {
font-size:20px;
}

.cat-label-2 h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.cat-label-2 h2:before,
.cat-label-2 h2:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
.cat-label-2 h2:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
.cat-label-2 h2:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

section.cat-label-2 {
max-width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 75px;
}

section.cat-label-2 h2 {
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<?php /* Template Name: Fashion-Home */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="cat-label">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
</section>
 
<section class="main-categories">
 <div class="cat-row">
  <div class="cat-title">
   <h4>Fashion</h4></div>
   
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=fashion&posts_per_page=2' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
     <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li> 
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by <span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Travel</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=2' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li>
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by <span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Interior</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=2' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li> 
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by <span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Work</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=2' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li>
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by<span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>
</section>

<section class="cat-label-2">
    <h2>Trending Stories</h2>
</section>

<section class="trending-categories">
 <div class="cat-row">
  <div class="cat-title">
   <h4>Fashion</h4></div>
   
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=fashion&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
     <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li> 
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by<span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Travel</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li>
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by<span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Interior</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li> 
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by<span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>

<div class="cat-row">
 <div class="cat-title">
  <h4>Work</h4></div>
 
 <?php query_posts( 'category_name=Travel&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>

 <ul class="posts">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   
     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(220,220)  ); ?></a></li>
   <li><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?></li>
  <li><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <li><p>by <span class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></span></p></li>
   
  
  <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  
 </ul>    
</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xttfQ.png)

Comment: just add `clear:both` in section.cat-label-2

Comment: Perfect. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You more than once open two `div`s like this

```
<div class="cat-row">
    <div class="cat-title">
```

with a `<ul>` following that contains `li` elements loaded with a PHP loop.

But later on, after the closing `</ul>` tag, you only have *one*  closing `</div>` tag, where there most likely should be two.